# filter lists of lists by taking out items less than a certain length - more pythonic way?

Tags: python, list

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655956/filtering-elements-from-list-of-lists-in-python), but I'm not sure how to do the same for looking at the length of individual items in a list. I have the following bulky code below, and I was wondering if there's a more pythonic way to do this?

```
indexdf =   [['1','','1',], ['1', '']]

listy = []
for ilist in indexdf:
    listx = [ ]
    #print ilist
    for x in ilist:
        #print x
        if len(x) > 0:
            listx.append(x)
    listy.append(listx)
```

output

```
listy = [['1','1']. ['1']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listy = [ [x for x in ilist if len(x) > 0] for ilist in indexdf]
```

There's a further trick since the "certain length" in your example happens to exclude precisely the empty strings:

```
[x for x in ilist if len(x) > 0]
```

could be replaced with

```
list(filter(None, ilist))
```

in Python 3 or just

```
filter(None, ilist)
```

in Python 2, or

```
[x for x in ilist if x]
```

in either of them.

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know you could do something like that!

Comment: Or just `listy = [ [x for x in ilist if len(x)] for ilist in indexdf]` since all values for `len(x)` except zero will be treated as true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension here. Note that empty strings will return `False` in a boolean context. The same is true for empty lists, tuples, etc.

```
>>> lst = [['1','','1',], ['1', '']] 
>>> lst = [[x for x in sl if x] for sl in lst]
>>> lst
[['1', '1'], ['1']]
```