# How to remove strings from a list of list of integers?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of integers and strings and I want to remove the strings. How would I go about doing this?

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,'test'], [6,7,84,3,2,4,'nan'], [4,1,2,4,5,42,4,'test']]
```

I have tried the following

```
for i in a:
for e in i:
    if isinstanece(e, str) == True:
        a.remove(e)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research? Please provide a [mcve] including _code_

Comment: one option is to `map` (or using list comprehension) your list and `filter` (or using list comprehension) each element using `instanceof` function, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655956/filtering-elements-from-list-of-lists-in-python) but with a bit different condition for the "filter"

Comment: Is it always the last element or is that just a bad example?

Comment: its just a bad example and there are multiple strings in each list

Comment: in your code, try `i.remove(e)`. Next time please put the code directly, not in edits

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehensions will achieve what you're looking for.

```py
[[val for val in lst if isinstance(val,int)] for lst in a]
```

edit: You could also check that the value is not a string:

```py
[[val for val in lst if not isinstance(val,str)] for lst in a]
```

Comment: I **think** `not isntanceof(val,str)` is more appropriate here